# Disable ibus in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I regularly switch between 3 scripts (English/Roman, Kannada and Hindi/Sanskrit/Devanagari).

In 12.04, I used to enable IBus by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch from English to Kannada, and again the same key to switch back to English. If I wanted to move to the next input method, I used to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>.

Now I have upgraded to 14.04. Here I see the option to move to the next and previous input method. However, I don't see any option to disable the input method completely and use the default (English) script.

So, If I have to switch from English to Kannada, I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and then from Kannada to English, I have to either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> twice, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Is there any way to just enable/disable the IBus input just like it was in 12.04?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to **Language Support** and Locate **Keyboard input Method System** and change it from **Ibus** to **None**.

[image: Language Support]

Comment: @techtonic : Why did you edit this answer after receiving my answer on your question http://askubuntu.com/questions/668388/troubleshooting-layout-switching-with-ibus-in-ubuntu-studio-15-04 ? Does this mean that it worked for you ? If yes, I think it would be fair enough to accept / upvote my answer !

Comment: @cl-netbox, probably I didn't see your answer while adding a picture here. Disabling IBus didn't help - it just disabled language switching support, and I haven't found a way to switch languages without IBus. How should it work without IBus?

Comment: @techtonic : Thanks! That's the elegant solution I was looking for. IBus conflicts with the default keyboard manager in Ubuntu 20.10 (using Cinnamon Desktop). The whole DE is slowing down by that conflict. After selecting "none", I can now use the defaut keyboard manager and Cinnamon become very responsive! Took me days to find that one